# How to change ordering in foreign key fields in django admin change_form

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, admin

I have two tables, tasks and projects. And every task has a project (and every project can have N tasks).

When adding or editing a task, projects are displayed as dropdown as it should, but dropdown is ordered by ID (or no ordering at all). Because i start to have plenty of projects, is there a way to get projects in a dropdown in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The objects should be ordered according to the [default ordering](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) specified on their model!

Comment: How stupid was i to not to look at that place. I was all wired up with admin.py .. Thankyou!